# Chrome developer tools closes JetBrains IDE support plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, phpstorm, remote-debugging

I debug with PhpStorm 2016.3 my JavaScript code remotely using JetBrains IDE support plugin for Chrome (my Chrome version is 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit), plugin version is is 2.0.9).

When I try to open Developer tools in Chrome, JetBrains IDE support plugin instantly closes connection.

[image: How it looks like]

Is it possible to keep both PhpStorm debugging plugin up and see what is happening in Network tab in Chrome?

Comment: AFAIK this is by design, you can't use both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a limitation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#simultaneous) in Chrome:

> We currently do not support multiple clients connected to the protocol simultaneously. This includes opening DevTools while another client is connected. On the bug tracker, [crbug.com/129539](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129539) follows the issue; you can star it for email updates.

Comment: Thx for answer. Is it somehow possible to use Firefox for same thing? I couldn't find similar JetBrains extension for Firefox.

Comment: @metamaker Honestly, no idea - I didn't even know this functionally existed in Chrome until I saw this question :)

Comment: Well ... you can debug JavaScript in Firefox ... but it's not so convenient as with Chrome. 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-firefox-remote.html ; 2) https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/06/webstorm-2016-2-eap-162-646/

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for links! :) So, this means that JetBrains officially decided not to support all features in Firefox.